# Http Post Bytearray from android

Tags: android, http-post, arrays

I want to post multiple byte array using http post in android. I am getting success to post single byte array using BYTEARRAYENTITY But posting multiple byte array in single request what should be change in the code ?

I write my code as below, which working fine to post one byte array. but waiting for solution to post multiple byte array.

```
public String postData2s(String URL, String data) {
    String filesizes = "";
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    String strresponse = "";
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    byteArray = data.getBytes();
    filesizes = byteArray.length + "";
    URL = URL + "&" + "fileSizes=" + filesizes;
    final DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = null;
    try {
        request = new HttpPost(URL);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    HttpResponse response = null;
    ByteArrayEntity arrayEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(byteArray);
    try {
        arrayEntity.setContentType("text/xml");
        request.setEntity(arrayEntity);
        response = httpClient.execute(request);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
                .getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String LineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line + LineSeparator);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        Log.e("response ", stringBuffer.toString());
        strresponse = stringBuffer.toString();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        strresponse = "";
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        strresponse = "";
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return strresponse;
}
```

My C# colleague uses following code to post multiple byte array for windows

```
 webRequest.ContentLength = size;

                Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();

                // Escribo cada uno de los archivos en el stream

                for (int i = 0; i < arrBytes.Length; i++)

                    requestStream.Write(arrBytes[i], 0, arrBytes[i].Length);

                requestStream.Close();
```

If any one have idea about this then please answer me asap

Thanks

Comment: convert that byte array to string and then upload multiple byte array to server

Comment: Can u give me example or change in my code ?

Comment: you need to download Base64 from http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/ also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451521/byte-array-to-string-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I am using below method to post data. that also include byteArray as one of the Field which is in String formate. You can use multiple field with multiple bytearray and it will do the job.

Code:

```
public static String UpdateUser(String userIdValue, String userNameValue, String nameValue,
        String emailIdValue, String contryIdValue,String countryNameValue, String stateValue, String cityValue ,String imageBytes){
    String res = null;

    HttpPut request = new HttpPut(USER_URL);
    //request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    //request.setHeader("user-agent", "Yoda");
    try {

        //-----------------
        /*InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream (getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.images));
        JSONArray array=readBytes(is);
        is.close(); */
        //----------------
        // Build JSON string
        JSONStringer jObject = new JSONStringer()
            .object()
                //.key("Get")
                  //  .object()
                        .key("Userid").value(userIdValue)
                        .key("UserName").value(userNameValue)
                        .key("Name").value(nameValue)
                        .key("EmailId").value(emailIdValue)
                        //.key("Password").value("")
                        .key("CountryId").value(contryIdValue)
                        .key("CountryName").value(countryNameValue)
                        .key("State").value(stateValue)
                        .key("City").value(cityValue)
                        .key("ImageByteArray").value(imageBytes)
                        /*.key("UserVerification").value("")
                        .key("City").value("")
                        .key("City").value("")*/
                   // .endObject()
                .endObject();

        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jObject.toString());
        //System.out.println("Our Res: "+jObject.toString());

        request.setEntity(entity);

        // Send request to WCF service
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        //res = response.toString();
        int resCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("Our Res: "+jObject.toString());
        System.out.println("Result code: "+resCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line="";
        StringBuffer returnFromServer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line=in.readLine())!=null){
            returnFromServer.append(line);
        }
        //Toast what we got from server
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),returnFromServer.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        System.out.println("Responce: "+returnFromServer.toString());
        res = returnFromServer.toString();

        if (entity != null){
            entity.consumeContent();
        }
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Responcre is:"+res);
    return res;

}
```

You just need to add extra parameter as number of byteArray you have.

Hope it will help you  lot.

Enjoy Coding.